# Installing cowpatty

Tags: aircrack-ng

I'm trying to install `Wifite` from [these instructions](http://tutorfreebr.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/wifite-ferramenta-facil-e-grafica-para.html), but I can't install `cowpatty`.

See below:

```
root@vitor-hp:~# apt-get install cowpatty
Reading package lists ... ready
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... ready
E: Could not find package cowpatty
root@vitor-hp:~#
```

<sub>Translated from Portuguese</sub>

I use Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you got it working? I have full script pm me.
As for just this part in question

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev libssl-dev
cd ~
wget http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/cowpatty/cowpatty-4.6.tgz/b90fd36ad987c99e7cc1d2a05a565cbd/cowpatty-4.6.tgz
tar zxfv cowpatty-4.6.tgz
cd cowpatty-4.6/
make
sudo cp cowpatty /usr/bin
cd ~
```

Comment: Just a heads-up that www.wirelessdefence.org is down and out…

Comment: link is not working anymore

Answer (score 3):

**According to the link you mentioned**

Cowpatty is not available in the Ubuntu repository and the link describes that you have to manually download it from the link mentioned..

Anyway I make it simple for you. Execute these commands in terminal to install `Cowpatty`:

```
cd ~
wget http://www.willhackforsushi.com/code/cowpatty/4.6/cowpatty-4.6.tgz
tar zxfv cowpatty-4.6.tgz
cd cowpatty-4.6
make cowpatty
sudo cp cowpatty /usr/bin
```

Now you've to continue with your steps...

Comment: When I use apeear
root@vitor-hp:~# python wifite.py

  .;'                     `;,    
 .;'  ,;'             `;,  `;,   WiFite v2 (r85)
.;'  ,;'  ,;'     `;,  `;,  `;,  
::   ::   :   ( )   :   ::   ::  automated wireless auditor
':.  ':.  ':. /_\ ,:'  ,:'  ,:'  
 ':.  ':.    /___\    ,:'  ,:'   designed for Linux
  ':.       /_____\      ,:'     
           /       \             
 [!] the program cowpatty is not required, but is recommended
 [+] scanning for wireless devices...
 [+] enabling monitor mode on wlan0... done
 [+] initializing scan (mon0), updates

Comment: I can't run wifite

Comment: Ok, after when I run root@vitor-hp:~# sudo cp cowpatty-4.6 /usr/bin and root@vitor-hp:~# python wifite.py nothing change.

Comment: @VitorMazuco: If you followed the steps very well then it is clear that the tutorial is a piece of s***. I've not found any comments which say that that it is working.. Forget it and don't waste your time to hacking some other system. Be a good man!! That's only I can suggest you.. Thanks to listen me!!

Comment: http://wirelessdefence.org/Contents/Files/cowpatty-4.6.tgz is offline now (`502 Bad Gateway`).

Answer (score 2):

#### Main answer

The appropriate way of installing `cowpatty` in your system is to grab a carefully packaged deb from a distribution that is compatible with Ubuntu.

My recommendation would be to grab `cowpatty` from [Kali Linux's repository](http://repo.kali.org/kali/pool/main/c/cowpatty/) and keep it updated with your system. You will not only have the version that others indicated, but also future versions updated automatically.

The appropriate entry for `/etc/apt/sources.list` would be, [according to the documentation](http://docs.kali.org/faq/kali-sources-list-faq):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

#### Addendum

This answer of mine tries to keeping in spirit with the "don't install packages from source if you don't have to" and to "stay only with packages from curated repositories". This applies in general and also especially for the case of security-minded people asking/learning about security.

Also, installing things from source and compiling yourself without them being in a Debian package makes `dpkg` (and higher level tools, like `apt` and `aptitude`) not aware of removing libraries that the tools depend on, like `libpcap` and OpenSSL (via `libssl`-variants).

There is a high probability of programs breaking when one of their underlying libraries is removed from the system (like OpenSSL pre-1.1 to OpenSSL 1.1 or [any other library transition](https://release.debian.org/transitions/) at all).

I understand that a Debian package may not have existed at the time the question was asked, but:

1. [Asking in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841472) or Ubuntu for a package like this is a very good way to have it included not only in your Ubuntu release but with high probability, in future ones, so that you can keep using the program.
2. Packaging programs is a very nice way to learn about the programs and your system in general and there are nice folks (including yours truly) that are always willing to help people enrich our distributions.
3. Expanding on the point above, when a package gets included in the distribution, its compiled/prepared version becomes available to every user of the distribution and it obviates the need of "I have the program and can send it to you privately". This is a contribution in the true spirit of "Free Software and giving back to the community" (even though I understand that, sometimes, you may simply want to use something quickly).
4. Once the package gets approved in Debian or Ubuntu, it can become available "forever" for future reference, since a snapshot of both its source version as well as its binary version are present at [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install libssl-dev

apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

then try `make`.

Comment: These are the correct, necessary, dependencies