# How do I install hackingtools that are not in repository?

Tags: ppa, software-installation

I tried to follow the instructions here: http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=73572

```
apt-get install nmap driftnet charon yamas wireshark tshark kismet cleven cowpatty
```

But some packages are not in the Ubuntu repository:

```
E: Paket charon can not be found.
E: Paket yamas can not be found.
E: Paket cleven can not be found.
E: Paket cowpatty can not be found.
```

How can I install the missing packages with `apt-get`?

Comment: "kann nicht gefunden werden" = "can not be found" in case there are people in the world that do not speak German ;)

Comment: please read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them (basically you need a PPA, include it in your system and then you can use apt-get)

Comment: So How do I find the right PPA's for each package?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/charon-suite/wiki/InstallationGuide

Comment: cowpatty: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362146/how-to-install-cowpatty

Comment: Oh and that command is for an installation of backtrack. Not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is a right place to ask such a question. You could just Google how to install specific tools on the operating systems you want. Its really simple.

Anyway, I know that is not the question. But I suggest u try Google for individual tools. Also please be specific next time, with little more details like what version of the OS you are using and what architecture it is.

Charon could be installed by adding the repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:charon-developers/charon-suite
```

The [source forge page of charon](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/charon-suite/wiki/InstallationGuide) explains this

Wireshark is in Ubuntu Repos.

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Yamas could be downloaded from [here](http://comax.fr/yamas.php) and [here](http://comax.fr/yamas/bt5/yamas.sh). This is for BackTrack, but it may work on Ubuntu also since both share same traits.

Installation of Cleven is detailed in [here](http://wiki.maemo.org/Cleven#Installation)

Am not sure if this is available for Ubuntu. Nokia N900 is the platform on which Cleven is used. AirCrack NG is the CLI version. Try installing it instead.

[Cowpatty](http://wirelessdefence.org/Contents/coWPAttyMain.htm) needs to be downloaded and installed using make command.

The best suggestion to you, is stop messing on head of Ubuntu and start using BackTrack.

Comment: Maybe you can add the dependencies on cowpatty?

Answer (score 0):

**To install charon:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:charon-developers/charon-suite
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install charon-utils-dev charon-flow-dev tuchulcha tuchulcha-doc charon-templates
```

**Install cowpatty:**

```
#Cowpatty is not available a PPA, so you have to manually download it:
cd /tmp
wget http://www.wirelessdefence.org/Contents/Files/cowpatty-4.6.tgz
tar zxfv cowpatty-*.tgz
cd cowpatty-*
make cowpatty
sudo cp cowpatty /usr/bin
```

take care to install the dependencies, otherwise you will get:

```
$make cowpatty
cc -pipe -Wall -DOPENSSL  -O2 -g3 -ggdb cowpatty.c -o cowpatty utils.o md5.o sha1.o -lpcap -lcrypto
cc: error: utils.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: md5.o: No such file or directory
cc: error: sha1.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [cowpatty] Error 1
```